# How to calculate lambda of Box Cox paramater to test stationarity of variants in Time Series

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, assumptions, stationarity

I want to test stationarity of variants using Box-Cox Lambda for Time series assumption (Stationarity).

Null-Hypothesis : Lambda is not zero (Data is stationarity of variants)

Alternative-Hypothesis : Lambda is zero (Data is not stationarity of variants)

But I got confused to obtain that lambda. Do you know the formula to obtain that lambda?

Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read [Guerrero, V.M. (1993) Time-series analysis supported by power transformations. Journal of Forecasting, 12, 37–48.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229710167_Time_series_analysis_supported_by_power_transformation)

The above paper is the only paper that I know of have developed automatic technique to determine  box cox transformation parameter lambda and importantly this procedure is model independent. This is done by minimizing coeficient of variation of time series. This is implemented in the `forecast` package in **R** software. See example below:

```
library('forecast')
lambda <- BoxCox.lambda(AirPassengers,lower=0)
```

There are better ways to test stationarities. Box cox transformation is used for stabilizing variance not to check stationarity. You might want to use specific procedures such as Ljung-Box test, augmented Dickey-Fuller test, ACF, PACF and others to check stationarity. See this [website](http://www.statosphere.com.au/check-time-series-stationary-r/) for a nice summary of methods and how to apply in $R$.

Comment: Thanks for respond, Actually I've used that code of R and I got Lambda = 1. But I need the exact formula for literature review of my research. I've already used the augmented Dickey-Fuller test for stationary test towards mean.

Comment: The exact formula is found in the paper and the R function BoxCox.Lambda. Again, this is not the right approach to test for stationarity.

Comment: Yeah i know. Which paper?